# A weird behaviour is with QLPreviewer or iPad Device that one docx file is not getting opened in device but works fine in simulator (iPad and iPhone)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8, ios8.1

I am using QLPreviewerController to open different format of files in iPad and iPhone for user to view but I'm suddenly getting a weird behaviour in iPad air & mini device (only two and not other iPad or air device) that one particular file with extension docx is not opening.

But same file is getting opened in simulator for iPad and iPhone (All devices of simulator including air and mini).

I did cross check that docx with other iPad air and mini device ,and  was working smooth.

So now stuck with why it is not opening in that particular iPad air and mini device?

Please find screenshot of iPad air device and simulator one below.

[image: iPad Air device]

[image]
Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please check if there is difference(Specially upper/lower case) issue with name of the file(the name you are using in code and actual document name).

Comment: There is no difference in name of document as same code is being run on device and simulator. Also weird is that is it working on other iPad device(physical one)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason for the above query and it is that the document( .docx file) itself is having a defect ,i.e., remove one particular image present in it and then it was getting opened.

Still I didn't find the exact reason that how it was running smooth in simulator and iPhone devices but not on iPad Air device.